# Concatenating variables

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create an expiration date using values selected from drop down lists on my web form, however I am unable to concatenate the Month variable value and Year variable value.  I get the error: Error Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.  I have tried to use the "+" also but get the same error.

Here is the code I have:

```
Dim Month = monthDropDownList.SelectedValue
Dim Year = yearDropDownList.SelectedItem
Dim MonthYear = Month & Year
Dim ExpirationDate As Date = MonthYear
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yearDropDownList.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: that fixed the error.  Who knew it was that simple.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want `SelectedItem`. You want `SelectedValue`. You should also explicitly declare your variables. You also can't create a Date in this manner. You need to use integers.

```
Dim Month As Integer= Convert.ToInt32(monthDropDownList.SelectedValue)
Dim Year as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(yearDropDownList.SelectedValue)
Dim ExpirationDate As Date = New Date(Year, Month, 1)
```

As a slight "cleaner" way to do this I would use:

```
Dim Month as Integer
Dim Year As Integer
Dim ExpirationDate As Date

Integer.TryParse(monthDropDownList.SelectedValue, Month)
Integer.TryParse(yearDropDownList.SelectedValue, Year)
If (Month > 0 AndAlso Year > 0) Then
    ExpirationDate = New Date(Year, Month, 1)
End If
```

Comment: what is the "1" for after month?

Comment: @Stizz1e: Going off memory (so I could be wrong), but I believe the constructor for Date wants a value for Day. Since OP isn't using day, 1 is a good guaranteed default value.

Comment: Joel thanks, that makes sense, also your clearer code worked I had to remove the second '&' though the compiler didn't like it.

Comment: @Stizz1e: HAH I'm sorry about that. I've been working in C# mostly lately so my brain is having trouble reverting to VB. That `&&` should be `AndAlso`.

Comment: No worries sir. It all helps.